# When is a Symmetric Block Toeplitz Matrix Invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, toeplitz-matrices, infinite-matrices

Let
$$
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_0 & Q_1 & Q_2 & \cdots\\
Q_{-1} & Q_{0} & Q_1 & \cdots\\
Q_{-2} & Q_{-1} & Q_0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be a block Toeplitz matrix with $Q_n\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ and $Q_{-n} = Q_{n}^{\sf{T}}$, i.e., $Q$ is symmetric. Additionally, let $Q_0$ be positive-definite.

**Questions:**

1. When is a finite such $Q$ invertible?
2. When does the inverse represent a bounded linear operator for infinite $Q$?